# Is anthropogenic global warming unavoidable under modern civilisation?

Tags: climate-change, co2, human-influence, fossil-fuel, predictability

Which are the reasons to believe that the climate crisis can be solved within our type of civilisation, that is, without putting in jeopardy the important advances of humanity that have been achieved within the industrial era?

[image]

[image]

Fossil fuel made it possible to feed more and more people and allowed higher and higher living standards to be achieved. It isn't realistic that billions of us will vote on parties that will decimate our standard of living. Has it been proved that this will not be necessary if fossil fuels are not to be used anymore?

[According to the WMO](https://public.wmo.int/en/media/press-release/new-climate-predictions-increase-likelihood-of-temporarily-reaching-15-%C2%B0c-next-5) there is a 40% chance of the annual average global temperature temporarily reaching 1.5°C above the pre-industrial level (the tipping point that has to be avoided according to the Paris Agreement) in at least one of the years 2021-25. This anthropogenic global warming is obviously a major threat, but how could the trend be broken without questioning basic advances that have been achieved in the modern epoch?

---

**Sources:**

The first figure shows the annual Keeling curve on a logarithmic scale (values minus 256).

The second is taken from https://industrialprogress.com/mcffdata/ fig 3:1 (including sources).

Comment: "Is there any reason to belive that the climate crisis can be solved within our type of civilisation?" Yes, there is reason to believe so. What does this have to do with the curve you are showing?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape - The curve shows that there's a steady trend in the increase of the atmospheric carbon dioxide. No break so far!

Comment: I do not see how the question is topical for this stack. Addressing climate change as a consequence of rising CO₂-level seems to be a question of political, sociological, and technological factors in human civilization.

Comment: @Lehs, yes I am able to read a plot. However the meaning of your question remains opaque. "Invariant" is a word coming from physics, indicating a quantity not changing its value under frame transformation, hence its use here is extremely confusing. If you are asking whether the rising trend shown in this plot will forever remain, I suggest you follow the trend back a few years.

Comment: please post some sources for the graphs you are using in your question.

Comment: @trondhansen - Upper curve is annual Keeling curve with logarithmic axis. 
The lower comes from https://industrialprogress.com/mcffdata/ fig 3:1 (including sources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an invariable and unavoidable correlation between economic growth and growth of CO2 emissions. Civilisation relying heavily on fossil fuels for energy will make CO2 levels rise as it grows but there are now other options for large scale energy production. Civilisation with zero emissions primary energy can grow without CO2 levels rising.